# omniauth-facebook gives "Error: An error occurred. Please try again later."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, facebook-oauth, facebook-login

I have Ruby on Rails site. Users are allowed to login using their Facebook accounts. Its done using `omniauth` + [`omniauth-facebook`](http://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-facebook) gems.

All worked well, but afetr *30 oct* facebook started to return "Error: An error occurred. Please try again later." message.

I think that issue linked with [Removal of offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). But removing 'offline_access' from requested scope not solved the problem.

Here is the query omniauth redirects to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=239854476109563&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inmyroom.ru%2Faccounts%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&perms=email%2Coffline_access%2Cuser_birthday%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_website&fbconnect=1
```

Any help. Thank you

---

UPDATE:
Oh, seems like I found the reason:
`Sandbox mode` was enabled automatically. And FB didn't allow me to disable it because my app have empty `privacy policy url` setting.

Comment: did you see this video - http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

Comment: Thank you for the link! I didn't see it... and seems like I found the reason of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason: Sandbox mode was enabled automatically (and I wasn't notified). And FB didn't allow me to disable it because my app have empty privacy policy url setting.

Answer (score 0):

in your **`omniauth.rb`** file

```
  provider :facebook, 'fb_app_id', 'fb_app_secret',{:scope => 'email, publish_stream', :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file => "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt" } } }
```

and more info see railcast video

http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication